# Is X11 cross-linux-platform and free from platform quirks?

Tags: linux, x11

Does X11 work across all linux operating systems? If I code a application that has an X11 window, will it look and operate the same across linux os's or will I have different tweaks I need to perform?

- Is there an alternative to X11 that is in c/c++ and low-level cross linux platform? *I'm aware of QT and GTK.
- What is the lowest level linux graphical system/windowing system?

Comment: Yes and No.  X is available for all linux distros.  but they all run different versions, perhaps with different compile-time options and default run-time configurations.  They all use or provide different window managers and desktop environments (which will radically change the window appearance). BTW, if you want your program to look good on a modern desktop, you almost certainly don't want to be writing code using only the X libs - use something "higher level" like Qt or GTK instead.

Comment: it will probably work the same, it will probably not look the same, because styling can be customised uising GTK and xresources etc...

Answer (score 4):

> If I code a application that has an X11 window, will it look and operate the same across linux os's

Yes, but not really for the reason you might think. X11 is very low level, and concerns itself basically with drawing graphics primitives and providing a reasonably standardized (note that this does not mean *sane;* X11 can be called many things, but I doubt "well designed for a modern environment" would be the first that lots of people would reach for) interface between the hardware input devices and the software. It doesn't even have much in terms of font and text drawing support; that's why libraries such as [Pango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pango) have been developed.

Actually, that's why toolkits such as Qt and GTK even exist: **those are not alternatives to X11** but rather build on top of it to make graphical applications programming much less of a headache. Because they abstract away all the nitty gritty details of how to actually *draw on the screen* they also enable porting of graphical applications to alternative platforms that do not natively support X11 applications, such as Windows.

If you want an alternative to *X11* then you are looking for something like [Wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/) which is [gaining some momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29#Adoption).

*If you are working with pure X11,* then the window content (not the window decoration such as title bar, window borders, etc.; pure X11 doesn't do window decoration, that task is delegated to the window manager) should always look the same, because your program is doing all drawing itself and you thus for better or worse have complete control over how the results look.

*If you are relying on some intermediate library* such as GTK, Qt or others, then your application's appearance may depend on how the user has configured that particular library to their personal tastes. If you want your application to be well received, you would be well adviced to accept those choices made by the user and make sure your application adapts gracefully to them.